# How to remove a resource from getting deleted in terraform(without failing the whole process)?

Tags: terraform

Does anyone know how to exclude a resource from getting delete in terraform?

- Removing that resource from tfstate file is not a good option because next time I am going to run terraform with throw an error that resource already exists.
- can't use prevent_destory. it will fail the process.

Comment: hi! Sorry I'm not fully understand your scenario..You want to make changes in a resource and as a result of these changes, the resource has to be destroyed..in that case you want terraform to ignore those changes and don't show any error. If that's your case I think that it cannot be achieved with terraform, as Terraform is a declarative language.

Comment: Nope. Let's take an example. Terraform creates all the resources and IAMs. Now I want all resources to destroy apart from IAM. As I have mentioned these IAM in another account for permission. Now if I remove the IAM from the resource file then on the next run it will throw an error that a resource with the same name is present already.

similarly, I can't use prevent_destory because this will fail the process.

Comment: You'll propably need to pull these resources out into a different terraform state/project, where you'll manage them as you see fit and then output their values into your other projects which needs to use them.